# Tag based search

Tags: search-engine

All the relevant information we need to pull up the relevant content is found in a database consisting of tags describing the relevant content. We match the search query with the relevant tags and pull up the information and rank them.

Example  content A  has tags 1,2,3,4,5 location of this content is Chicago

Content B has tags 3,7,8,9 location of this content is London

Content C has tags 1,9,8,0 location of this content is Chicago

Content D has 7,3,4,0,2 and is located in Chicago and was viewed more than the other three when someone searched for 761 and were from Chicago.

Now the user has searched for 761 and his location during the search is Chicago

Now I would want the search to rank content C ahead of B because C also is relevant in two parameters the  location from where the query came from and a matching  tag .

I would rank C ahead of A as the relevant tag 1 is selected out of a choice of 4 (which means there is a 25% match with the content vs A where its chosen out of 5 (where it would be a 20%).

And pull up content D and also show the user that content D was viewed more by those who search for 761 and were located in Chicago.

So the end result should look like this

Content A

Content D **most viewed by users

Content C

And last content B.

This is what I would like the search engine to do .It does not have to  search on websites or within the content it self. Now what would be a better direction for me to take when looking for a search engine solution to work within my APP .Or would you say my requirements are simple enough to build one instead.

Comment: You could use a system of fixed ratings and a formular that applies the weight for each condition by multiplying it with some variable factors.
e.g. multiply by the distance from the location / 1000; possible would also be to multiply by "distance" in the data-structure if you have some graph based data structure etc...

Comment: addition: have a look to search engine ratings, how e.g. google is sorting its results keyword: page-rank. now you will need to develop your own page-rank-algorithm that is suitable for your situation